# Is there a way to see wait pid details in pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql

To see what's happening in the DB I can use a query on pg_stat_activity to see what all the processes are currently doing.

When I get a log like `process 1019106 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 18314 of database 16402 after 1000.127 ms at character 2859 Processes holding the lock: 1013210, 1009626. Wait queue: 1019040, 1019105, 1019106.` is there a way to get the process id's holding the lock into that pg_stat_activity query output?

I can make pg_stat_activity give me a table of pid, user, state, wait event type, wait event, state change time, and sql.

What I want is to add a column to that table so I can see the pid's it's waiting on.

Comment: Join to `pg_locks`, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pg_blocking_pids()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.4.2.2.12.1.1.1) to obtain a list of PIDs that are blocking that process:

```
select pid, usename, state, wait_event_type, wait_event, 
       pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by
from pg_stat_activity
```